# Proper Apache redirection from http to https

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, redirection, htaccess

I set up a new virtual host for a new site on my server, but it's acting strangely despite having the exact same settings as my original site.

I want all requests to be redirected to HTTPS, simply put. On my main site (the working one) I have this specified in the `VirtualHost` config, and in `.htaccess` I have an additional rule specified to allow short URLs. Specifically, the problem on the non-working site is that if I try to go to `example.com/url`, the redirect goes to `https://example.comurl` and removes the necessary `/` from the URL.

I copied the exact config over to the new `VirtualHost` and `.htaccess` file from the working site so I'm not sure why it doesn't work on the new one. My DNS records for both sites all use A records to point to it, no redirects or anything happen at the DNS level. I have tried putting a `/` at the end of the `Redirect` lines in the code below, but the problem was not resolved. The server is Ubuntu 14.04, and Apache is version 2.4.7. Both sites are separate domain names with separate `.conf` files used, but they are hosted on the same server with the same IP address. How can I fix this problem?

The relevant code in the `VirtualHost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

In case it helps/matters, this is the SSL config in my VirtualHost file, though it is placed at the very beginning of the file outside of all other directives:

```
SSLCipherSuite AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdo$
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

SSLCompression off
SSLUseStapling on
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"
```

And this is the config specifically for the `VirtualHost` for the site:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin user@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/errorexample.log
    Options -Indexes

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example/examplecert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example/examplekey.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/chain/class1.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: have you got SSL defined?

Comment: Maybe different Apache versions? And have you tried putting the slash at the end of the Redirect line? Like this? `Redirect permanent / https://example.com/`

Comment: I do have SSL defined, I added the relevant code blocks to the OP. I also did try putting a `/` at the end of the `Redirect` command, but that did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To redirect to HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But you need to have a virtual host for ssl:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
</VirtualHost>
```

**NOTE:** you have to create a SSL certificate... but there is [great tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-12-04) for this!

Comment: Huh, this appears to have resolved the problem. I already had the SSL virtual host specified (I suspect you were writing this answer while I was editing mine to add that in), but I changed my `Redirect` lines to your first code block instead and everything works properly now. Thank you so much!

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: Can you check this link :http://askubuntu.com/questions/876767/how-to-match-port-to-redirect-to-https-on-apache2

Comment: where does the rewrite engine stuff go, in the vhosts file?